# Modify form field before it gets to params (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Searched all over internet but can't find any answer to my problem..

I have form, where user can input time in on of the following formats - HH:MM:SS or MM:SS or seconds. Lets call this model LapResult and the fiel name is lap_time.
I need to do calculations with this data, so i need to keep it in seconds as integer in DB. For example to calculate total time of all laps, or calculate the difference between two competitors.

I've tried two solutions:

1) lap_time column in DB is integer. But after passing some time to model, since the data type is integer, the input automatically transforms. For example if I enter 11:56 - it will be 11 in model instance.
`params[:lap_result][:lap_time] = 11:56
lap_result = LapResult.new(lap_result_params)`

Now if I call before_save of before_validation or other callback, I will manipulate with number 11, because race_result.lap_time now is 11. I guess it automatically was changed because column data type is integer.

2) also I've tried to change params (or copied variable of params) before passing in to new LapResult model. This method works perfectly for what i'm looking for - time successfully converted to integer, but then i encounter another problem.
If user inputs didn't pass validation for some reason, when the page reloads, params are not transferred to form and the user must input all data again. And this is problem, because sometimes there can be up to 20 laps in race..

Currently I solved this by changing data type to string, but i feel that doing it this way is bad practice because the data in DB should always be an integer type. And because in other models same data have integer type in DB. It doesn't feel like good idea for convention over configuration principle.

Any advices from rails guru?
Thanks in advance.

--
Bonus question! If form didn't pass validations and the page reloads with all its data, for sure it is displayed now in seconds. Any way to transform it to MM:SS format again. I guess it is easier to do this kind of job with javascript. Any ideas?
ps: multiple forms created using total_laps.times { lap_results.build } since it's form with nested models, so i cant find the way to set value by hand from params.

Comment: _2) also I've tried to change params (or copied variable of params)..._ Did you make a deep copy of the params hash via `clone` before modifying them? If you keep the params intact the form should pick them up.

Comment: nope, dont know about clone method. just assigned params to new variable and then modified it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try overriding the `lap_time=` method

```
class LapResult    
  def lap_time=(value)
    lap_time_in_seconds = # ... logic to convert value MM:TT to integer

    # set the value that will be saved to the database
    self[:lap_time] = lap_time_in_seconds
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats what I was looking for!
Converting time string to seconds integer correctly, and also re-displaying data in case of validation fail and page reload.
The only thing left now is to convert integer to time formated string when page is reloading due to validation fail.

Can you suggest where I can find this function in rails api?